# Making Changes in CoreData record, SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, edit

I'm learning Core Data with SwiftUI. I want to make an app where I can post Movies I liked, make a review and add rating.

I can already add new Movie in my app, delete it, see Details of Movie. Now I want to Edit my record in CoreData. I found it difficult, because I don't know how to place default values to my Form from edited Movie.

My code:

```
struct EditMovieVIew: View {
let movie: Movie
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

@State private var title = ""
@State private var director = ""
@State private var review = ""
@State private var genre = "Fantasy"
@State private var rating = 3
@State private var productionYear = Date()


    let genres = ["Sci-Fi","Fantasy", "Comedy", "Horror", "Thriller", "Criminal", "Kids", "Romance", "Drama"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Name of movie", text: $title)
                    TextField("Director's name", text: $director)
                }

                Section {
                    DatePicker(selection: $productionYear, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
                        Text("Date of production")
                    }
                }

                Section {
                    Picker(selection: $genre, label: Text("Genre")) {
                        ForEach(genres, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0).tag($0)
                        }
                    }
                }.navigationBarTitle("Select your cheese")

                Section {
                    RatingView(rating: $rating)

                    TextField("Write a review", text: $review)
                }

                Section {
                    Button("Save") {
                        let newMovie = Movie(context: self.moc)
                        newMovie.title = self.title
                        newMovie.director = self.director
                        newMovie.rating = Int16(self.rating)
                        newMovie.review = self.review
                        newMovie.genre = self.genre
                        newMovie.productionYear = Int16(Calendar.current.component(.year, from: self.productionYear))

                        try? self.moc.save()
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()


                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Add Movie")
        }

    }
}

struct EditMovieVIew_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)

static var previews: some View {
    let movie = Movie(context: moc)
    movie.title = "Test Movie"
    movie.director = "Test director"
    movie.genre = "Fantasy"
    movie.rating = 4
    movie.review = "Good movie"
    movie.productionYear = 2019

    return NavigationView {
        EditMovieVIew(movie: movie)
    }
}
```

}

I was also trying to make

```
@Binding var movie: Movie
```

But non of my ideas worked.

Where is the problem?
When I want to assign a value to my TextFields and Pickers, I can't use my

> text: $movie.title. //OR text: movie.title //OR text: self.movie.title

So next what I wanted to do was to assign default values to my @State values. I've written:`@State private var title = self.movie.title` but Xcode said than I can't use `self` and `movie` here.

So my question is - how can I set default start values for my TextFields so I will be able to edit my movie and update it in my CoreData?

PS. And I have another problem. I want to make DatePicker for only picking year. Now I have full picker and then I'm using only year of User's pick, but I think it would be better to pick just a year

[I want TextFields to have default value got from original movie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn0YI.png)

Comment: If you want to edit/update a movie then you need a Movie objected fetched from your Core Data store to get the values from and to save when the changes are done but right now you are saving a new instance. I haven't used SwiftUI and Core Data much together but I guess you need that movie property to be an observed object. Also, you should remove that PS from your question and only ask one thing at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do this in a custom `init` function. Because they are `@State` wrapped, you will need to jump through one tiny hoop to set them up properly.

```swift
@State private var title: String // don't set up any initial value here

init(movie: Movie) {
  self.movie = movie
  self._title = State(initialValue: movie.title ?? "")
  // etc.
}
```

Note the `_title`, this means you're initialising the wrapper and not the wrapped value.

For problem 2, if you only care about year, consider storing `DateComponents` instead of `Date` and just set up a custom picker rather than a `DatePicker`. Populating an array of years going back to 1850 (or whenever) is pretty simple. Or have a year text field. Many ways to accomplish this.